# Excel 2007 Sharing Violation error on a standalone PC

Tags: microsoft-excel

On my home PC, why do I get the Excel Sharing Violation error while performing a Save operation in MS Excel 2007?

The exact error message is:

> Your changes could not be saved to
>   'filename.xls' because of a sharing
>   violation.  Try saving to a different
>   file.

I can understand if this error comes in a network environment, but what's wrong with my standalone PC?

Comment: I am not facing this problem with excel 2003 protected file but with excel 2007 protected file. There is no problem with unprotected excel files.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem and it is saved to a local folder that I created. The problem seems to happen in Word 2007 as well, although there it is easier to recover from (just use Save As).

**Note:** I have seen [elsewhere](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/fi-FI/w7files/thread/0b0067aa-0c76-433c-bcdd-93b0e30c678a) that it might be a Trend Micro problem.

**Note 2:** My sys admin pointed out this was due to the Microsoft Indexing Service in Windows 7. I used advanced properties on the folder and removed the indexing of file contents and the problem has gone!

Answer (score 1):

It means that you already have the file open (or the computer thinks you do anyways). Did Excel crash?

You might try copying the file to a new name or rebooting your computer.

Comment: Its a Single User PC and Excel didn't crash anytime yet.  Using the Save As operation does work.  But this problem again comes up with some other Excel file.  I need to understand the Root Cause.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to be in a network environment to get sharing errors.  It can also mean that two programs locally try to use the same file at the same time.

There seems to be a problem with Excel 2007 on Windows 7, that results in being unable to save an XLS or XLSX file after editing it, if the file is located on your desktop.  Move it to the Documents folder or any user-created folder on harddisk, and it will work.